# How to make user select a photo album in windows phone 8

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8

I'm coding a windows phone 8 application.

I want user to select a photo album (not a photo in an album).
So i'll do something for all photos in that album.

Is there a object do this?

I use vb.net for coding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no. [This is a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769543%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) of Windows Phone choosers. It seems that [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) can only pick photos, not entire albums.

Comment: Yeah i went over PhotoChooserTask object but as you mentioned it works for one photo. Is there another way to get the list of albums?